What is the text encoding of the MySQL Slow Query Log?
The documentation does not seem to contain the word "encoding", so I am looking for a reference on the encoding of the MySQL slow query log.
Based on the slow query logs I have seen so far, my current guess is that it is ASCII rather than UTF-8, but there are also strange characters that look like raw bytes for binary columns, so I am wondering if anyone knows what the intended encoding is, and whether it is documented anywhere.

I don't find it in the documentation either, but FWIW the mysql.slow_log table for table-based logs uses mediumblob, so that would definitely be binary, with no text encoding.

That's helpful to know, thanks!

Are you talking about the FILE version of the slow log?  Or th TABLE` version?

The FILE version.
